# Why amazon gives an error occurred fetching Instance data at EC2 instance dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have several already running EC2 instances but Today when I login to Amazon and go to the EC2 instance dashboard it gives me "An error occurred fetching Instance data".

And it is also not showing any running instances and instead of showing the count on the dashboard it's showing "Error retrieving resource count".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm also seeing the same problem. Basically AWS is having problems with their EC2 API on us-east-1. I would wait it out a bit and have them fix it.

You can check the overall AWS health status here:  http://status.aws.amazon.com/

Here's a screenshot of the status as of 06:14 UTC time:

[image: AWS health]